# How to filter with a regex what's the user is typing in a Vuetify combobox to create a chip?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I am trying to allow only a certain regex pattern when the user is typing in a comboox to create or add a new chip (basically for example if you want the user to only be able to add phone number chips).

- Full Vue Source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/chips-so-0gp7g?file=/src/domains/experimental/Experimental.vue
- Preview: https://0gp7g.csb.app/experimental
- Relevant piece of Vue Source Code:

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-combobox
          v-model="chips"
          chips
          :delimiters="[',']"
          append-icon=""
          clearable
          hint="Hey I'm a  hint!"
          persistent-hint
          label="Type your favorite s"
          multiple
          solo
          @input="meowInput"
          @change="meowInput"
        >
          <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item }">
            <v-chip
              v-bind="attrs"
              close
              :color="getColor(item)"
              @click:close="remove(item)"
            >
              <strong>{{ item }}</strong
              >&nbsp;
            </v-chip>
          </template>
        </v-combobox>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import ColorHash from "color-hash";

export default {
  name: "Experimental",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      select: [],
      chips: [],
      search: "", //sync search
    };
  },
  methods: {
    meowInput(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
    getColor(item) {
      const colorHash = new ColorHash({ lightness: 0.9 });
      return colorHash.hex(item);
    },
    remove(item) {
      this.chips.splice(this.chips.indexOf(item), 1);
      this.chips = [...this.chips];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How can I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: have you try vuelidation?

Comment: @Jazuly it doesn't really address the issue, for validation purposes in the same context of combobox + chips, there is that thread on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519878/vue-vuetify-how-to-make-a-validation-on-each-chip-item-instead-of-the-entire

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this working is to evaluate the input against a regex (I used US numbers here, but you can use whatever you need) and, if it does not pass the regex test, pop the value out of the `chips` array.

You can see what I did below. Hopefully this gives you something to go off of:

```js
    <template>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-combobox
              v-model="chips"
              chips
              :delimiters="[',']"
              append-icon=""
              clearable
              hint="Hey I'm a  hint!"
              persistent-hint
              label="Type your favorite s"
              multiple
              solo
              @change="meowInput" // I changed this to @change so it executes when the user hits enter
            >
              <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item }">
                <v-chip
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  close
                  mask="###"
                  :color="getColor(item)"
                  @click:close="remove(item)"
                >
                  <strong>{{ item }}</strong
                  >&nbsp;
                </v-chip>
              </template>
            </v-combobox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import ColorHash from "color-hash";
    
    export default {
      name: "Experimental",
      components: {},
      data() {
        return {
          select: [],
          chips: [],
          search: "", //sync search
        };
      },
      methods: {
        meowInput(e) {
          // Test if the input string matches the specified regex pattern
          if (!/^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/.test(e)) {
            console.log("invalid!");

            // Remove from the chips array
            console.log(this.chips);
            this.chips.pop();
          } else {
            console.log("phone number");
            // Automatically added to the chips array
          }
        },
        getColor(item) {
          const colorHash = new ColorHash({ lightness: 0.9 });
          return colorHash.hex(item);
        },
        remove(item) {
          this.chips.splice(this.chips.indexOf(item), 1);
          this.chips = [...this.chips];
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting, I'm gonna reflect on your answer.